# Can I use RxJava2 and RxAndroid in a single java class library?

Tags: rx-android, rx-java2

I'm tasked with creating an SDK that can be consumed from both Android & Java applications using [ReactiveX programming](http://reactivex.io/). I already have an android project using [RxAndroid](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxAndroid) created, but now I need to extend it with [RxJava2](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava).

The question I'm facing is whether I should create 'regular' java class library and use it for both scenarios or create 2 separate packages (which would mean a lot of duplicate code + maintenance).

Is this even possible? And if so, is it a good practice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> whether I should create 'regular' java class library and use it for both scenarios

Yes. What I would do to start is simply change your Android library project to be a standard Java library and replace RxAndroid dependency by RxJava. Most code should still compile. Code which doesn't will mostly use schedulers provided by RxAndroid and can be changed to take `Scheduler` parameters.

Then create an Android Library project which depends on the Java Library and put the RxAndroid-specific code there.

Comment: I did just that and all seems to be working well, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

As an addition to @AlexeyRomanov's answer, feel free to check out this library which could be used for both Android and Java projects: https://github.com/JakeWharton/RxRelay.

Its basically an extension to RxJava, but it might give you a solid idea where to go. Good luck!